# Typogrify: hyphenation not kicking in

Tags: craft3, plugin-typogrify

I am stunned by the typogrify extension for craft. https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-typogrify

Alas, the functionalities that are most relevant to me are not kicking in (anymore). 
As Andrew says on https://nystudio107.com/docs/typogrify/#troubleshooting

> If it doesn't look like Typogrify is doing anything to the HTML you're
>   passing it, it is probably malformed HTML (syntax errors, missing
>   closing tags, etc.). Fix your HTML, and Typogrify will prettify it!

Well, in my case it's not, I'm outputting a text-only-field in a completely empty page.

```
{{ entry.lead|typogrify|smartypants }}
```

Most things are working: for example `(c)` is replaced by `©`, and I can switch it on or off with `"set_smart_marks" => true,`

But I can't get the Hyphenation to work:

```
// enables hyphenation of text
"set_hyphenation" => true,

// defines hyphenation language for text
"set_hyphenation_language" => "de-CH",
```

At one point, the content was full of `&shy;`s which seemed to come from Typogrify. Not anymore. Why could that be?

I don't understand where typogrify gets the hyphenation rules from: maybe it requires additional php libraries that are missing?

Also, I wonder how – when it works – to switch the hyphenation language in a multilingual site?

---

**[SOLVED:]**

**Quotes to guillemets**

I wanted to convert all kinds of accidental double quotes into swiss style `«Guillemets»` (like the french, but there's no space).

I tried:

```
// curl quotemarks
"set_smart_quotes" => true,

// Primary quotemarks style
// allowed values for $style
"doubleGuillemetsFrench" => "&laquo;&nbsp;foo&nbsp;&raquo;",
"set_smart_quotes_primary" => Quote_Style::DOUBLE_GUILLEMETS_FRENCH,
```

The reason it wouldn't work were surplus spaces in twig:

```
{{ entry.lead | typogrify | smartypants }}
```

instead of

```
{{ entry.lead|typogrify|smartypants }}
```

Comment: I'm on it... ...

Comment: I thought maybe there was a difference between my local environment and the web server. But it's behaving completely the same on local as on remote.

Comment: Can you add your solution as an official answer instead of editing the question to add it?

Comment: Right; I should have made 2 questions. I hope I get the first part solved and then I‘ll add it to the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding/changing the hyphenation settings in the config file? e.g.

```
// establishes minimum length of a word that may be hyphenated
"set_min_length_hyphenation" => 5,

// establishes minimum character requirement before a hyphenation point
"set_min_before_hyphenation" => 3,

// establishes minimum character requirement after a hyphenation point
"set_min_after_hyphenation" => 2,
```

I ran into a similar problem. There were defaults set, but to get it to work, I had to explicitly add them to my file.

Comment: I have that in already...

Comment: what language are you using it with? And can you explain me how it works in the first place? I mean, is this relying on some PHP modules with hyphenation rules, or how does it do the trick? Also, is it better than browser-side hyphenation – which is superbad for German..